# Trying to deserialize object sent over bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, deserialization

Trying to deserialize object sent over bluetooth from one android device to another.

The object size is *126* bytes and I'm taking in exactly that size. However I'm getting a class not found exception.

**The code for deserialization is:**

```
public static EcgDataPoint deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
        return (EcgDataPoint) o.readObject();
    }
```

**Error:**

```
tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth D/BluetoothReaderThread: Data type doesn't match
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tech.abhinavdas.bluetoothpairingclient.models.EcgDataPoint
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1615)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1520)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1776)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.models.EcgDataPoint.deserialize(EcgDataPoint.java:54)
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.deserializeAndRead(BluetoothReaderThread.java:47)
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.run(BluetoothReaderThread.java:38)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tech.abhinavdas.bluetoothpairingclient.models.EcgDataPoint" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth-EZqoTdreOfJT1jU4xbF9dg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth-EZqoTdreOfJT1jU4xbF9dg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1615) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1520) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1776) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) 
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) 
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.models.EcgDataPoint.deserialize(EcgDataPoint.java:54) 
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.deserializeAndRead(BluetoothReaderThread.java:47) 
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.run(BluetoothReaderThread.java:38)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" - the correct class in your classpath. It cannot be found.

Comment: Can you elaborate or explain the fix? thanks!

Comment: Where is your EcgDataPoint class located? It cant be found

Comment: It's in the same package as the class trying to deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types with the same name:

```
tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.models.EcgDataPoint
```

and

```
tech.abhinavdas.bluetoothpairingclient.models.EcgDataPoint
```

So: in this line of code:

```
return (EcgDataPoint) o.readObject();
```

Make sure the type you're casting to is tech.abhinavdas.bluetoothpairingclient.models.EcgDataPoint.

Also, double check you don't have a mismatched version of the code on the sending side (these two packages look eerily similar in name).

Comment: Seems like the problem..I'll try to force the package name as same.

Comment: getting

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 67446174
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at tech.abhinavdas.datapoint.EcgDataPoint.deserialize(EcgDataPoint.java:67)
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.deserializeAndRead(BluetoothReaderThread.java:50)
        at tech.abhinavdas.bluetooth.threads.BluetoothReaderThread.run(BluetoothReaderThread.java:38) @not-a-jd

Comment: Are you using an ObjectOutputStream on the sending-side?

Comment: Yes I am..

ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(this);
        return b.toByteArray();